# Aggregate function in spark-sql not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and I am trying to make use of some aggregate features, like sum or avg. My query in spark-shell works perfectly:

```
val somestats = pf.groupBy("name").agg(sum("days")).show()
```

When I try to run it from scala project it is not working thou, throwing an error messageé

```
not found: value sum
```

I have tried to add

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
```

just before the command, but it does not help. My spark version is 1.4.1 Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need this import:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Comment: Yep, thats it! I haven't found any info about this import in spark-sql documentation. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sum method directly on [GroupedData](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData) (groupBy return this type)

```
val somestats = pf.groupBy("name").sum("days").show()
```

Comment: How to set alias name for days? since it returns sum(days)

Comment: Find out, toDF() is the choice, `rdd.toDF("name", "days")`